# BS5 - Background image looks poor when on mobile screen

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
[Img1][1]
[Img2][2]
[Img3][3]
```

Hi all,

In process of learning Bootstrap grid system at the minute and am having issues with making my background image scale down properly for smaller screens/sizes.

I've provided couple of screenshots above that will hopefully help with getting appropriate advice. As you can see from there my background image gets shrinked width wise but I would like for it to be scaled down to center of the image as the screen size gets smaller.

Beginner here so apologies in advance for any potential mistakes in the code above.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @moony_ The images in your post are not displaying but from reading the description try this in your CSS.

```
background: url(...path-to-your-image...) 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Take a look at the Stack Overflow Tour if you get a minute, it's worth a read >> https://stackoverflow.com/tour